# How much 4 digits numbers , that their sum equals 10 , and And there are no two adjacent digits that their sum is 5 , we have?

Tags: combinatorics

I got that i have 286 (4 digit numbers) that their sum equals 10 , Then I checked 3 invalid cases:

x1 + x2 = 5

x2 + x3 = 5

x3 + x4 = 5

I got that I have 5 options for case 1 (one option less than cases 2-3 , because 0 as a first digit is invalid) , and 6 options each of cases 2-3.
So I need to subtract 286 - 5 - 6*2?

Comment: Do you mean the sum _of digits_ is $10$? And what are indexed digits? Adjacent digits?

Comment: @ShubhamJohri yes for your 2 questions.

Comment: Cases $1$ and $3$ are equivalent. If $x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4=10$ and $x_1+x_2=5$, then $x_3+x_4=5$. How did you get $5$ for case $1$ and $6$ for case $2$?

Comment: Ok , so there only 11 (instead of 16) illegal numbers of 286? I get 5 for case 1 with (6 C 5) - 1 = 6 - 1 = 5 cases (-1 because then x1=0 and x2=5 is illegal), and (6 C 5) = 6 cases for case 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Case $1$:** $x_1+x_2=5$

Thus, $(x_1,x_2)=(1,4),(4,1)(2,3)(3,2),(5,0)$, a total of $5$ possibilities. Since $x_3+x_4=5,(x_3,x_4)$ can also be one of the five options for $(x_1,x_2)$ or $(0,5)$, i.e. a total of $6$ possibilities. Thus, we have $5\times 6=30$ numbers satisfying this case.

**Case $2$:** $x_2+x_3=5$

We have $6$ possibilities for $(x_2,x_3)$ and $5$ for $(x_1,x_4)$. But we also need to ensure that no number out of these $5\times6=30$ possibilities has already been counted under case $1$. For a number to satisfy both cases $1$ and $2,x_1+x_2=5=x_2+x_3\implies x_1=x_3$ and $x_2=x_4$. These numbers are $1414,2323,3232,4141$ and $5050$.

You need to subtract $30+30-5=55$ from $286$.

Answer (score 2):

To solve the problem you have to count the cases that contain a subset of indexed digits that their sum is 5. There are 2 cases:

1. $a+b=5$ and $c+d=5$;
2. $b+c=5$ and $a+d=5$;

Where $a,b,c,d$ represent the digits of $\overline{abcd}$.

The second case contains also $a+d=5$ that is not a sum of indexed digits but it is necessary because you know that the total sum is 10. By the fact that you can form 5 as sum of 2 numbers in 6 ways (5 with non-zero first digit), in both cases you have $5\cdot 6=30$ numbers.

You may have count two times some cases so you have to control if can be possible that:

$a+b=5,\quad b+c=5,\quad c+d=5, \quad d+a=5$

By the fact that $a+b=5$ and $b+c=5$ we have that $a=c$ that implies also $b=d$. We have to count the numbers $\overline{abab}$ with $a+b=5$ that are exactly 5.

In conclusion the solution is $286-60+5$